# Show that $\mathbb{R}^k$ is separable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A metric space is called separable if it contains a countable dense subset.

I have no idea how to go about proving this. What sort of things should I understand to do this. What would a sample proof look like?

Comment: Do you know what it means for a set to be dense?

Comment: Do you know why $\mathbb R$ is separable?

Comment: Think rational...

Comment: Yeah, for a set to be dense, for every a in our set A, that point A will include a point from our metric space X.

Comment: @J.r That seems a little off to me. The definition I learned is that a subset $A \subset X$ is dense if $\overline A = X$. That is, the closure of $A$ gives you $X$.

Comment: $A$ is dense in a metric space $X$, if for every point $x$ in $X$, for every ball centered in $x$ this ball contains some element of $A$. If you prefer every point in $X$ the limit of a sequence in $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're looking for something that's countable and dense.   The natural thing to look at would be $\mathbb Q$.   In this case,  look at $\mathbb Q ^K$.   It's countable as it's a finite crossproduct of countable sets.  To show it's dense, you have to show that every point in $\mathbb R ^k$  is a limit point of $\mathbb Q^k$.    For that,  use a sequence approach (Decimal approximations is the natural one)

Answer (score 2):

Since this is also a question with "general-topology" tag:

Theorem: Let X and Y be separable topological spaces. Then $X \times Y$ is separable.

Proof: There are two countable sets $A \subseteq X $ and $B \subseteq Y$ such that $\overline A=X$ and $\overline B =Y$. Since A and B are countable $A \times B$ is countable too.

For an arbitrary $(x,y) \in X \times Y $ holds: For every open neighborhoods $U,V$ of $x$ and $y$ the intersections $U\cap A$ and $V\cap B$ are not empty, hence the intersection $U \times V \cap A \times B$ is not empty too.

From this it follows that the intersection of $A \times B$ with every open neighborhood containing $(x,y)$ is non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Explore some properties of $\Bbb{Q}^k$